# Finding longest consecutive range of numbers

Tags: c

I've been struggling with finding the longest consecutive range of numbers that are greater than 1.
An example:
0
0
0
1
2
1
2
2
2
3
3
0.
I'm not really sure how to go about this. Essentially my goal is to find where the starting value is and where the range ends.

```
 typedef struct fitbit
{
    char minute[9];
    double calories;
    double distance;
    unsigned int floors;
    unsigned int heartRate;
    unsigned int steps;
    Sleep sleepLevel;
} FitbitData;

typedef enum sleep
{
    NONE = 0, ASLEEP = 1, AWAKE = 2, REALLYAWAKE = 3
} Sleep;

void sleep_level(FitbitData *arr)
{
    char *start;
    char *end;
    int max_sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].sleepLevel > 1)
        {
            start = arr[i].minute;
            max_sum += arr[i].sleepLevel;
        }
        else if (arr[i].sleepLevel == 1 || arr[i].sleepLevel < 1)
        {
            end = arr[i].minute;
        }
    }


    printf("The longest range of consecutive starts at %s and ends at %s",start,end);
```

Comment: Is arr[i].minute just the index?  Also, it looks like you don't need the conditional for the else if or the while, and you don't need to declare int i on line 3.

Comment: yeah, arr[i].minute is the index. That is where I would begin storing the values that I need. I need the conditional so that I don't check the values that are less than 1.

Comment: Please edit your question to give the declaration of `arr` and of the `struct` containing `.minute` & `.sleepLevel`

Comment: I've included the structs for .minute, and .sleepLevel.

Comment: Are you looking for the largest sum of numbers, or the longest sequence?  The title says 'longest sequence'; the code seems to be trying for 'maximum sum'.  You don't seem to track current sum (or current length) separately from maximum sum (or maximum length).  You probably need both the current and the maximum.  You can reset the current values on reading a non-positive (zero or negative) value.  You also have to worry about data with no trailing zeros; it might be the sequence you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum sleep
{
    NONE = 0, ASLEEP = 1, AWAKE = 2, REALLYAWAKE = 3
} Sleep;

typedef struct fitbit
{
    char minute[9];
    double calories;
    double distance;
    unsigned int floors;
    unsigned int heartRate;
    unsigned int steps;
    Sleep sleepLevel;
} FitbitData;


void sleep_level(FitbitData *arr, int n) {
    char *start;
    char *end;
    int max_sum = 0;

    char *current_start;
    char *current_end;
    int current_sum = 0;
    int i;

    if (n < 0)
        return ;

    current_start = current_end = arr[0].minute; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i].sleepLevel > 1) {
            current_sum += arr[i].sleepLevel;
            current_end  = arr[i].minute;
        }
        else {
            if (current_sum > max_sum) {
                start   = current_start;
                max_sum = current_sum;
                end     = current_end;
            }
            do
                i++;
            while (i < n && arr[i].sleepLevel <= 1);
            if (i >= n)
                break;
            current_start = arr[i].minute;
            current_sum   = arr[i].sleepLevel;
            current_end   = arr[i].minute;
            }
    }

    if (current_sum > max_sum) {
        start   = current_start;
        max_sum = current_sum;
        end     = current_end;
    }

    printf("The longest range of consecutive starts at %s and ends at %s\n",start,end);
}

int main(void)
{
    FitbitData arr[12];

    strcpy( arr[0].minute, "a");
    arr[0].sleepLevel = 0;
    strcpy( arr[1].minute, "b");
    arr[1].sleepLevel = 0;
    strcpy( arr[2].minute, "c");
    arr[2].sleepLevel = 0;
    strcpy( arr[3].minute, "d");
    arr[3].sleepLevel = 1;
    strcpy( arr[4].minute, "e");
    arr[4].sleepLevel = 2;
    strcpy( arr[5].minute, "f");
    arr[5].sleepLevel = 1;
    strcpy( arr[6].minute, "g");
    arr[6].sleepLevel = 2;
    strcpy( arr[7].minute, "h");
    arr[7].sleepLevel = 2;
    strcpy( arr[8].minute, "i");
    arr[8].sleepLevel = 2;
    strcpy( arr[9].minute, "g");
    arr[9].sleepLevel = 3;
    strcpy( arr[10].minute, "k");
    arr[10].sleepLevel = 3;
    strcpy( arr[11].minute, "l");
    arr[11].sleepLevel = 0;


    sleep_level(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been struggling with finding the longest consecutive range of numbers that are greater than 1

That's not what your code does. You'll want something along the lines of this pseudo code:

```
int current_size = 0;  // size of the current sequence
int current_val = 0;   // value of the current sequence   
int longest_size = 0;  // size of the longest sequence
int longest_val = 0;   // value of the longest sequence

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(array[i] != 0)
  {
    if(array[i] == current_val)
    {
      current_size++;
    }
    else
    {
      current_val  = array[i];
      current_size = 1;
    }

    if(current_size > longest_size)
    {
      longest_size = current_size;
      longest_val  = current_val;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful.

```
int max = 0, temp = 0, end = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(arr[i] > 1) temp++;
  else 
  {
    if(temp > max) 
    {
      max = temp;
      end = i
    }
    temp = 0;
  }
}
```

At the end of the code the max length of the sequence will be stored in max, the end point will be stored in end and if you want the start you can do

`int start = end - max + 1;`